# variable not being set to correct value in jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x

I'm relatively new to python, and I've gotten stuck on a problem:

Printing

```
sub2(x_eq,t,TIME)
```

gives

```
[ 0.          0.44508534  0.67843048  0.74471979  0.70970004  0.53404757
  0.14018878 -0.33691033 -0.63391147 -0.73733656]
```

While

```
x_points=sub2(x_eq,t,TIME)
print(x_points)
```

gives

```
[102.66143508  79.77874816  21.62259676  -4.52895461   9.89269732
  63.13232847 101.94641713 112.58619799 168.77080144 206.69523487]
```

No errors, no nothing. Just incorrectly assigned variable.

(the rest of the code)

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import t,x,y,z
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def sub2(eq,var1,var2):
    l3=var2
    for i in range(0,len(var2)):
        l3[i]=eq.subs(var1,var2[i])
    return l3

def getTangentLineParametric(x_eq,y_eq,loc_t):
    dx_dt=diff(x_eq,t)
    dy_dt=diff(y_eq,t)
    dy_dx=dy_dt/dx_dt
    slope=dy_dx.subs(t,loc_t)
    tanline=slope*(t-x_eq.subs(t,loc_t))+y_eq.subs(t,loc_t)
    plt.figure()
    TIME = np.arange(0,5,0.5)
    x_points=sub2(x_eq,t,TIME)
    print(type(x_points),type(sub2(x_eq,t,TIME)))
    print(sub2(x_eq,t,TIME))
    y_points=sub2(y_eq,t,TIME)
    y_tanlin=sub2(tanline,t,TIME)
    print(x_eq,x_points,y_eq,y_points)
    plt.plot(x_points,y_points,color="blue")
    #plt.plot(TIME,y_tanlin)
    return tanline

getTangentLineParametric(sin(t),3*t**3,2)
```

Printing the types of x_points and sub2(x_eq,t,TIME) gets:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Trying to print before assigning shows they are uninitialized, so that's not a problem.
However...

y_points is the exact same as x_points resulting in a y=x line

Output equation works properly though: 36*(t - sin(2))/cos(2) + 24

This is all very confusing and I have no clue why the variable wouldn't be set correctly

I'm using jupyter notebook

---

note: sub2 is just the subs function, except you can input a list/array instead of just a single integer/float

further testing reveals the output of sub2 changes each time it is executed

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, but the method is not known, sub2 changes the value of TIME.

Applying the fix of

```
TIME = np.arange(0,5,0.5)
```

before using TIME each time fixes the problem. Once again, no clue why this happens... But it is what it is.